# Subway magnetic fields and laptop hard drives

Tags: physics, electromagnetism, magnets, hardware

I just heard a story of a guy who took the subway to transport his company's off-site data back-ups for storage. When the time came for restore after a disaster, the data was corrupt and erased.

Being from New York City like I am, this makes me nervous about even my laptop.

Is this subway magnetic field an urban legend, or should I beware?

Comment: This question is old, however all the answers were ureferenced and low quality and I've removed them.

Comment: @Sklivvz: My answer, which you deleted, is an answer to the OP's question.  S/he is asking whether she has any reason for concern: I explained how to eliminate that concern.

Comment: This is not SuperUser.com. We aren't here to find alternatives to solve people's computer problems. We are here to address claims with empirical evidence.

Comment: Don't post answers in comments, thank you.

Comment: Magnetic fields are just one factor. Electric fields, static electricity, radiation, and even shaking might have an effect.

Comment: **If you are thinking of answering**: Do not post theoretical answers. Read [this](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2929/faq-what-are-theoretical-answers?cb=1) before answering. Theoretical answers will be removed. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Oddthinking also note, if this is specific to NY's subway there might be some part of it which does corrupt (not erase) data because it's particularly magnetic. Norms and measurements do not necessarily cover every square meter of the underground. Also, the media might have been of poor quality or old, thus more susceptible than assumed. This is to say: the proof is in the pudding, not in the recipe.

Comment: If I'm remembering the story correctly he was transporting tapes.  They're much more vulnerable.

Answer (score 6):

No, subway magnetic fields might not cause hard drive data corruption and erasure based on the measurements taken for magnetic field strengths on the electrically powered trains which operate on alternating current such as the New York city subway and the Baltimore Washington commuter train. The measurements taken on the Baltimore Washington commuter train in 1991 showed 25 hertz magnetic field strengths as high as 500 milligauss in passenger areas at [seat height](http://nepis.epa.gov/Exe/ZyPDF.cgi/000005EP.PDF?Dockey=000005EP.PDF). This is calculated as 500 milligauss equals to 0.5 Gauss (0.5 Oe) which is very minimal compared to the required magnetic field strength of 5000 gauss and above needed to erase data from hard drives.

The highest magnetic field '30 milligauss' measured in Toronto subway is actually 0.03 Gauss (0.03 Oe) which is also below the magnetic fields needed to erase data from hard drives. Magda Havas et. al. [2004](http://www.magdahavas.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/04_Havas_transit.pdf) reported that,

> The highest magnetic fields were found in subways (mean 30 mG, range 3 to 100 mG), followed by streetcars (mean 30 mG, range 2 to 100 mG), buses (mean 11 mG, range 1 to 50 mG) and the GO-train (mean 2 mG, range 1.2 to 2.8 mG). The magnetic field increased with acceleration and deceleration and varied with seat location and this was most obvious in subways and streetcars.

After the data is stored, a strong interfering magnetic field could reverse the orientation of some or all of the grains in a bit cell, possibly converting a zero to a one or vice versa causing corruption of the data in the hard disk.  The ability of the magnetic material to resist this phenomenon is known as coercivity and modern magnetic media with Cobalt based coatings in disk drives can be on the order of 1000 times higher coercivity than earlier used storage media [Yang, 1991](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jap/69/11/10.1063/1.347501).

"DC magnetic field exposure at and above 255 Gauss causes undesired but temporary performance degradation in the hard drives tested.  Exposures up to 305 Gauss caused no loss of data, and no permanent [damage](http://www.datacenterdynamics.com/critical-environment/magnets-in-the-data-center-dangerous-for-data/71328.fullarticle)".

> Two different models of hard drives were tested in non-time varying magnetic fields of various strengths. The impact of the magnetic flux exposure was quantified by performing data transfer rate benchmark testing, data integrity tests, predictive testing, and surface scanning on the drives before, during and after exposure.  The drives were found to be largely immune to magnetic flux densities up to approximately 250 Gauss (0.025 Tesla).

The earliest hard disks (IBM’s 1956 model) used iron oxide as the magnetic material. The low coercivity of iron compounds explains that there was little resistance to data corruption from external magnetic fields. Iron compounds were commonly used in the floppy disks of the 1980’s and 1990’s. Floppy disks are vulnerable to damage from even relatively weak magnets [Keizer, 2004](http://www.techhive.com/article/116572/article.html).

Small rare earth magnets are commonly used in consumer products, and their usage is increasing. For example, the iPad 2 product by Apple Inc contains 31 magnets, 21 in the device’s folding cover, and another 10 in the iPad itself. Yet the servers, laptops and hard drives in proximity to all these iPad magnets are not [failing](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6651655).

The only magnets powerful enough to remove all of the data from a magnetic hard drive are laboratory products known as [electromagnetic media degaussers](http://www.archives.gov/frc/flyers/e-media-destruction-faqs.html). These devices operate above 5000 Oe.